# Getting "-bash: edit: command not found" in terminal

Tags: objective-c, bash, terminal, cocoapods

While trying to setup a Podfile using `edit Podfile`, I get this

```
-bash: edit: command not found
```

Am I doing something wrong here? How can i fix this and setup my Podfile

Comment: just open it with any text editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you make a typo?

Try seeing to which program 'edit' points. You can do so by typing the following command:

```
which edit
```

It should show you where 'edit' is located on your filesystem. I take it 'CocoaPods' is an Apple thing? On my system, I have no 'edit' and I don't think it comes with OS X.

Are you simply trying to edit a text file? Just use something like '**nano Podfile**' instead. Nano is a simple text editor that comes with Unix systems.

Comment: Tried "which edit" and nothing happened. Tried nano Podfile a text editor in the terminal came up but I don't really know my way around this so I would like to figure out why "edit Podfile" doesn't work. I'm working with CocoaPods

Comment: Nvm, I went ahead and edited it through the terminal.. Weird how "edit Podfile" won't work.. Thx